# Imagens sumindo do meu aplicativo usando Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Fiz um aplicativo utilizando o Xamarin Forms Cross Plataform, a principio só preciso da versão de android dele então não estou me importando com IOS e Windows. O aplicativo está funcionando corretamente quando testo ele em um dos meus celulares um Xiaomi Redmi 4x, mas quando testo ele em um Xperia Z1 ou outro celular com menos capacidade de processamento as imagens ficam desaparecendo. Elas aparecem e desaparecem conforme eu vou pra outras páginas. Ao total o aplicativo tem 143 imagens e não tem como eu mudar isso. O aplicativo consiste basicamente em textos e imagens. Uso ContentPages e CarouselPages. Exemplo de uma das partes onde uso imagem:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="Imagem1Geral.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            <Label  Text="Posição Inicial&#x0a;"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="30"
                TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Não sei o que fazer para as imagens pararem de sumir...

Answer (score 0):

Vou te dar uma dica de um componente que sempre utilizo para imagens em xamarin forms : [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) . Com ele é possível utilizar cache e otimizar o carregamento das imagens.